GitHub Actions Self-Hosted Runner Build code
I have following that needs to be executed through a self-hosted runner.
MSBuild HelloWorldCustomRunner.sln /property:Configuration=Release /t:Clean;Build
I keep getting the below error:
Build is not a recognized cmdlet
